# why django restframework api do not work with LocaleMiddleware?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a drf api "POST /api/session/" to login

I use angularjs to do that

```
$resource('/api/sessions/:id/').save()
```

At first eveything is ok, until I add `LocaleMiddleware`.

setting.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-cn'
LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', 'Engilsh'),
  ('zh-cn', u'简体中文'),
)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
url(r'^sessions', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
)
```

When I try to call `$resource('/api/sessions/:id/').save()` again, the Django console said

```
[04/Nov/2015 09:09:51] "POST /api/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

[04/Nov/2015 09:09:51] "GET /zh-cn/api/sessons/ HTTP/1.1" 405 45
```

that means LocaleMiddleware redirected my request from `/api/sessions/` to `/zh-cn/api/sessons/`, but "POST" to "GET" made my request error.

How can I stop LocaleMiddleware modifying "POST" to "GET"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the language prefix for your rest framework url, move it outside your `i18n_patterns`. In your urls.py, you can combine `i18n_patterns` with regular lists of url patterns.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sessions', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
    ...
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
   # note the '' isn't necessary in Django 1.8+ 
   # your patterns that you do want to internationalize go here
)
```

See the docs on [language prefix in URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) for more info.

Comment: i want to internationalize 'rest_framework_jwt', but 'rest_framework_jwt' locale just have 'en'

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible to 'internationalize it but only have one language. Could you use the above answer, but use `r'^/en/sessions'` as the regex?

Comment: i tried force "$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US';" and "$resource('/api/sessions/:id/').save()" works well, so this mistake was because locale just have no 'zh-cn'.

Answer (score 0):

"$resource('/api/sessions/:id/').save()" is wrong! should change to "$resource('api/sessions/:id/').save()", first slash make url wrong